# How to run this Vue project?

Tags: vue.js, npm

I'm new to the Vue project and currently exploring it. I download a project from git and try 'npm run serve' but showing an error "missing script: serve". So I try to build one from scratch, and it can run properly. The differences are:-

project from scratch

```
{
  "name": "test-vue",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

the project which I get from git

```
{
  "name": "testBot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "testBot",
  "main": "main.js",
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "vue-i18n": "^8.24.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.21"
  }
}
```

How can I run the the project I get from git

Comment: Run `npm install` to install all dependencies

Comment: And then `run npm serve`

Comment: already run "npm install" and run "npm run serve" ready , still show this error

Comment: Are you running it from the correct project directory?

Comment: yes, I use pycharm ide, opened the project, and run the command from that terminal

Comment: _"I download a project from git"_... got a link? I can 100% say that it is not a Vue application project

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that your project built from scratch has this lines:

```
"scripts": {
   "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
   "build": "vue-cli-service build",
   "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
},
```

There are like aliases for commands from Vue CLI. You could try adding them to your downloaded project.

But underlying problem is probably that you don't actually have Vue added to this project. It isn't inside dependencies. In that case you could just run `vue create [name-of-your-app]` and it should take care of everything.